# Como capturar el evento click de un Jcombobox

Tags: java-swing

tengo el siguiente código para un jcombobox, donde necesito poder capturar también el evento cuando haga clic en uno de los items del mismo.

```
private void initComboKeyListener() {
    filterEditor.getFilterLabel().addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
                    if (!Character.isDefined(keyChar)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
                            return;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                            selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                            resetFilterComponent();
                            return;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                            resetFilterComponent();
                            return;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE:
                            filterEditor.removeCharAtEnd();
                            break;
                        default:
                            filterEditor.addChar(keyChar);
                    }
                    if (!comboBox.isPopupVisible()) {
                        comboBox.showPopup();
                    }
                    if (filterEditor.isEditing() && filterEditor.getText().length() > 0) {
                        applyFilter();
                    } else {
                        comboBox.hidePopup();
                        resetFilterComponent();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a cuando cambien la selección del item?

Comment: si cuando le da click con el mouse dentro de la lista desplegada del combo

Answer (score 0):

Para eso se necesita el `ItemListener` lo puedes agregar de la siguiente forma.

```
TuJcomboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
    //tu código
  }
});
```

Este escuchará cuando el item seleccionado haya cambiado.

Comment: gracias , tu respuesto me ayudo a encontrar la solucion de que solo detecte cuando sea con elick.

Answer (score 0):

Estimados encontré esta manera para identificar unicamente cuando el evento provenga de la acción del mouse.

```
        private void initComboMouseListener() {
       comboBox.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(" ################ mouseClicked");
            selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            resetFilterComponent();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(" ################ mouseEntered");
            selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            resetFilterComponent();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
```